# Multiple form ID's in HTML5's input form attribute

Tags: html, forms

The HTML5 input element includes a 'form' attribute, which can contain one or more space delimited form id's. See below for a simplified example, where both form1 and form2 share an input element.

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<input type="text" form="form1 form2">
```

At least, that's how it's supposed to work:
http://swatelier.info/at/forms/HTML5attrib.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp

In Chrome 28, I see that adding a second form id hides an input element from both forms. What modern browsers, if any, support this functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure, but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form): "...An input can only be associated with one form." [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) seems to win yet another time :)

Comment: A littlebit late, but I answered to same question in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52419757/2492784

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowhere in the spec says that the value of the `form` attribute is a space-separated list of IDs of form elements in the document:

> If a reassociateable form-associated element has a form attribute specified, then that attribute's value must be the ID of **a** form element in the element's owner Document.

Source: [WHATWG HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form)