# Can a textarea belong to multiple forms?

Tags: html

I have a textarea similar to

```
<textarea name="mytextarea" form="form1 form2"></textarea>
```

When inspecting the element and viewing node attributes, it shows the form as null. This is in chrome.

Inputs can have multiple form attributes, but can textareas?

It's different from the other question because it pertains to text areas, not other inputs. Though, the result may ultimately be the same.

I received my initial apparently incorrect information from this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

See form on that page. Either way. This can stay closed. It is obviously not implemented in the browsers or ever specified in the spec.

Thanks all.

Comment: right now, it'd be looking for a form with ID `form1 form2`. I would ask what you're trying to do-- chances are you can re-design it to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960834/multiple-form-ids-in-html5s-input-form-attribute) states, nowhere on the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/association-of-controls-and-forms.html) is stated that the form owner of an element can be a list of IDs. If for some reason, that is working for you, you're still not conforming to standards.

I suggest using jQuery if you want to submit multiple forms at the same time, or duplicate the value of input elements across different forms on submission.